# Switch role in Snowflake Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Cant switch role in Javascript Procedure.

In my Snowflake Javascipt Procedure i try the command:

```
snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "use role sysadmin" });
```

Stored procedure execution error:

```
Unsupported statement type 'USE'.
At Statement.execute, line 49 position 13
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Hi - what about the error message is unclear to you? The error has got nothing to do with the code within the SP

Comment: Sorry, pasted wrong error message. Error message is: Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'USE'.
At Statement.execute, line 49 position 13

Comment: Again, what’s unclear about that error message? “use” statements are unsupported. In any case, why would you need to switch role in the middle of a SP?

Comment: The error message is not unclear. I have a procedure executing tasks on behalf of different roles (fex creating role, warehouse, database and doing grants I would do it using different roles). So to simplify how can i execute "use role sysadmin" in a procedure?

Comment: You can’t. You need to run the SP using (or the SP needs to be owned by) a role that has the necessary privileges to execute all the statements in the SP

Answer (score 0):

Try executing it as caller:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE useroletest()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$

snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: `USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;`} ).execute();

$$

;
```